# How to create Dynamic tabs in react js

Tags: reactjs

Hi how do create dynamic tabs? I wrote like this for 2 tabs. If it is more, it automatically adds those tabs. Can you please help with this?

From that, it should create 2 tabs.  And it should set the correct URL when you click on the tab. If it gets more dictionary items in the array then it creates more tabs

Comment: Please post your code and what you have tried, otherwise will be really hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

What your searching for is `React.createElement`.

You can create a component from a string :

```
React.createElement('Upgrade')
```

for example.

However, dynamically creating a function in `Webshop` seems not feasible.
If you only need to do a `history.push(PATH)`, I would recommend putting the function inside an `onClick` event. I'm not sure how do you want it to work.

Comment: I didnt get you. Please help with this

Comment: You need to explain what you didn't get

Comment: I am new to React js. So I didn't get your answer. I need dynamic tabs. please help

Comment: Come on man, try a little. Tell me what exactly you didn't get.